# Как задать TextView функцию перелистывания текста, или как это реализовать через другой UIОбъект

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Есть набор текста, текста довольно много,   он помещается в `textView`.

Как разделить этот текст, на отдельные фрагменты, и, что бы, они переписывались, в `textView`, `тачем`, либо кнопкой (наподобие `eBooks`)?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: У меня есть большей объем текста который надо пометить в textView. Я хочу этот текст разбить на фрагменты и реализовать перелистывание станиц, проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как реализовать перелистывание.

Comment: если вы знаете, как разбить текст на страницы - уберите это из вопроса. про перелистывание уже дали ответ.

Comment: К сожалению с этим вопросом мне тоже нужна помощь...

Comment: А вы уже что то пробовали в этом направлении? хоть какой то код есть?

Comment: Всё получилось, спасибо!! тему можно закрыть.

Comment: ну тогда либо публикуйте свой ответ, либо удаляйте

Answer (score 1):

Эта анимация создаётся таким путём

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет!